# Can't load AVDs with certain APIs on Windows 10

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, android-virtual-device

For instance AVD's with Android 6 can't be loaded, there are screen with with "android" title and nothing more. AVD's with some more older Android versions (2.3.3 for instance) can be loaded.
Using latest Android Sutido/SDK/Build Tools.
Tried to use older SDK Build Tools, change CPU, use Host GPU, change amount of RAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstallation of Windows solved the problem.